# Forth floating point calculation with local variables

Tags: forth, gforth

In Forth, it's possible to use the separate floating point stack for division and multiplication. A typical example to calculate 3/4 is:

```
3.e 4.e f/ f.
0.75  ok
```

which is 0.75. But what will happen, if the calculation is done within a word, which is using local variables?

```
: calc { a b } 
  a b f/ f.
;
3.e 4.e calc 

:2: Stack underflow
3.e 4.e >>>calc<<< 
Backtrace:
$7FDF1C7C1220 >l
```

It seems, that Forth has expected a value at the integer stack which is empty, because before the function call, the variables were put to the floating stack. The question is how to modify the calc-word in a way, that the local variables are taken from the float stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify that the variables be floating point by using the `F:` type specifier.

```
: calc { F: a F: b }
   a b f/ f.
;
3.e 4.e calc \ => 0.75  ok
```

For details, see [section 5.21.1](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Gforth-locals.html) in the gforth manual.

Comment: @ruvim what I showed in my original answer, before your edit, was exactly what was output by gforth.

Comment: it is convenient if an example code can be pasted as is, so output is usually not included into the code but rather in comments (if any).